Handling Platform Applications in AWS SNS
I am creating a Mobile Application where I am using AWS SNS for handling the notifications.
I want to send individual notifications to User, so the I haven't created any Topics.
Currently I am working only on Android Notifications. 
The Complete logic for this is written in a lambda function.
I will be using 2 lambda functions :

One for handling the creation of Platform applications an saving their arns in my DDB.
Second for actually sending the notification to the user.

What I did till now:

Getting device token from the user and using it to create an endpoint in my sns.
Creating an Platform Application Endpoint of the user with this endpoint .
Saving the platform application to my Database.
Sending notification based on the saved endpoint ARN.

Problems I faced.

How can I handle the scenario when my user logins to a different device which will have
different token and an endpoint too.
Should I be deleting the platform application endpoint of an user when he logs out and
also erase his saved endpoint from my database?
Do i need to always check on my App Launch if the users device token is same ?
How can i handle the scenario of users device token changing. Does the whole endpoint
change after that?
How can i handle the disabled endpoints, Is there a way to delete them  via lambda
functions or my frontend code?

